# How to keep collored output using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, gnu

Hi I'm using `sed` command and I want to keep collored output from previous command.

```
la | sed -En  '/Desktop/q;p'
```

But sed cut off all color codes

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://superuser.com may be a better place to ask this sortsa question :)

Answer (score 2):

Is `la == ls -A`?

If yes: add option `ls --color=always`.

Otherwise, colours are deactivated if the output does not go to a tty.

Comment: I don't se this option on osx, maybe osx sed don't have this option?

Comment: It's an `ls` option. For sed, escape sequences are not special.